# C++ calculation with type "long"

Tags: c++, types, precision

I have a inline function does a frequency to period conversion. The calculation precision has to be using type **long**, not type **double**. Otherwise, it may cause some rounding errors. The function then converts the result back to **double**. I was wondering in below code, which line would keep the calculation in type **long**. No matter the parameter bar is 100, 100.0 or 33.3333.

```
double foo(long bar)
{
  return 1000000/bar;
  return 1000000.0/bar;
  return (long)1000000/bar;
  return (long)1000000.0/bar;
}
```

I tried it myself, and the 4th line works. But just wondering the concept of type conversion in this case.

**EDIT:**

One of the error is 1000000/37038 = 26, not 26.9993.

Comment: Just so you know, an integer value stored in a double won't have rounding errors unless it exceeds the range of the mantissa, typically 2**52.

Comment: bar cannot be 33.3333 when passed as a long. It will be converted to 33.

Comment: bar cannot possibly be `100.0` or `33.3333`. You should use 1000000L as the constant.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Although it might have more precision than if the same operation is performed on an integral type (maybe that is what he means?)

Comment: Are you looking for something like a [rational number data type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/rational/)?

Comment: PS: Could you elaborate on the rounding errors you expect? To give advice, you have to tell about the range of values passed to your function and the rounding error you ar willing to accept. Depending on the actual system, it might be an option to use long double type or some other extended precison type supported by your compiler (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double). Note however that AFAIK in MS VC++ long double is just a synonym four double and won't help you there.

Comment: @Fred, not exactly. One of the bug I am having now is 1000000/37038 = 26. Not 26.9993.

Comment: Have you tried the second line, with the return type changed to `long`? Or `return (long)(1000000.0/bar);`?

Comment: @Stan: If you do integer arithmetic (which is what you say you want, "has to be using type `long`"), then you will get integer results: 26, not 26.9993. If you want non-integer results, then you'll need to use floating-point (or rational, or whatever) arithmetic, not integer; for example, `return 1000000/double(bar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem, as you posed it, doesn't make sense.

`bar` is of an integral type, so `1000000/bar` will surely be less than `1000000`, which can be represented exactly by a `double`<sup>1</sup>, so there's no way in which performing the calculation all in integral arithmetic can give better precision - actually, you will get integer division, that in this case is *less* precise for any value of `bar`, since it will truncate the decimal part. The only way you can have a problem in a `long` to `double` conversion here is in `bar` conversion to `double`, but if it exceeds the range of `double` the final result of the division will be 0, as it would be anyway in integer arithmetic.

Still:

```
1000000/bar
```

performs a division between `long`s: 1000000 is an `int` or a `long`, depending on the platform, `bar` is a `long`; the first operand gets promoted to a `long` if necessary and then an integer division is performed.

```
1000000.0/bar
```

performs a division between `double`s: `1000000.0` is a `double` literal, so `bar` gets promoted to `double` before the division.

```
(long)1000000/bar
```

is equivalent to the first one: the cast has precedence over the division, and forces `1000000` (which is either a `long` or an `int`) to be a `long`; `bar` is a `long`, division between `long`s is performed.

```
(long)1000000.0/bar
```

is equivalent to the previous one: `1000000.0` is a `double`, but you cast it to a `long` and then integer division is performed.

---

1. The C standard, to which the C++ standard delegates the matter, asks for a minimum of 10 decimal digits for the mantissa of `double`s (`DBL_DIG`) and at least `10**37` as representable power of ten before going out of range (`DBL_MAX_10_EXP`) (C99, annex E, ¶4).

Comment: "which can be represented exactly by a double" <- False. One tenth can't be exactly represented by binary IEEE representations, just like one third can't be exactly represented in a finite decimal expansion.

Comment: @Tinctorious: that "which" refers to `1000000`, that *can* be represented exactly by a `double`. The result of the division may or may not be represented exactly, but in this case you get surely a better precision with `double` division than with `long` division (that truncates the decimal part).

Comment: @Tinctorius He said that `1000000` can be represented exactly as a `double`.  Formally, I'm not sure it's guaranteed by the C++ standard, but I've never heard of an implementation where it wasn't true.

Comment: I stand corrected. Perhaps I should take more time to read... words ;)

Comment: @JamesKanze: it seems that it's guaranteed, see the updated footnote.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I know that it guarantees at least ten digits precision for double.  But ten digits isn't exact; one could imagine a double representation in which integers weren't exact---say a representation which actually stored the value divided by 1000000.  I'm not sure that this would be legal, either, but it would probably pass under the as if rule, if nothing else.  In practice, of course, all implementations of floating point do make integers exact, at least in a certain range, so in practice, it's not something we have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

```
return 1000000/bar;
```

This will do the math as a long.

```
return 1000000.0/bar;
```

This will do the math as a double.

```
return (long)1000000.0/bar;
```

This is equivalent to the first -- 1000000.0 is a double, but then you cast it to long before the division, so the division will be done on longs.

Answer (score 1):

The first line (and third more verbosely) will do the math as `long` (whihc in C++ always truncates down any result) and then return the integral value as a double. I don't understand what you're saying in your question about `bar` being `33.3333` because that's not a possible `long` value.